# Navigation (and status) bar colors different than programmed (alpha automatically set to 0.85)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

**The objective**

I'm trying to color my navigation bar grey (RGB 33, 33, 33). The problem is, I always get a much lighter color when I use the color :

`UIColor(red: 33/256, green: 33/256, blue: 33/256, alpha: 1)`

**The problem**

So I've had to darken the color to RGB 8,8,8 for this to work (Verified using the digital color meter: getting the (33,33,33) grey I want).

**The code**

The code I'm using to do this is copie below:

```
    //  NAV BAR
    let navigationBarAppearace =  UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.03, green: 0.03, blue:0.03, alpha: 1)
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    
    //  STATUS BAR APPEARANCE
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
```

**What I've found**

I've investigated using the Xcode debug view hierarchy, right clicking on the nav-bar and pressing 'print description'

[image]

to get this :

`<_UIVisualEffectSubview: 0x15422d1c0; frame = (0 0; 375 64); alpha = 0.85; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d4224c60>>`

Meaning the alpha is already set to 0.85 (even though i never explicitly set it to that value), whether in Interface builder or anywhere in code.

If I want to color any other view with the same color as the navigation bar, I use :

`UIColor(red: 0.03, green: 0.03, blue: 0.03, alpha: 0.85)`
equivalent to
`UIColor(red: 8/256, green: 8/256, blue: 8/256, alpha: 0.85)`

(same RGB with an alpha of 0.85)

**The question**

How can I remove the 0.85 alpha on the navigation bar to use the same color values throughout my app ?

Comment: Did you make sure that the `UINavigationBar`s `isTranslucent` property is set to `false`? The default is `true`

Comment: Thank you ! yes that did it. For future readers, this transates to `navigationBarAppearace.isTranslucent = false` in my code

Comment: `UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false` if you are using the `Appearance Proxy`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write the following code

```
navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: Thank you ! yes that did it. For future readers, this transates to `navigationBarAppearace.isTranslucent = false` in my code